# WebStorm doesn't use tsconfig compiler options (Angular app)

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, tsconfig

I have a default project structure generated by `angular-cli`, where there is a root `tsconfig.json`, `src/tsconfig.app.json` and `src/tsconfig.spec.json`. Though I have `noImplicitAny` and `strict` options turned on in root config, I get no error squiggles in my editor when I don't specify function arguments types or assign `number` typed variable to `null`.

How can I configure WebStorm to use my root `tsconfig.json` to provide hints for me?

Here is my root `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "strict":                     true,
    "strictNullChecks":           true,
    "noUnusedLocals":             true,
    "noUnusedParameters":         true,
    "noImplicitAny":              true,
    "noImplicitThis":             true,
    "noImplicitReturns":          true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
}
}
```

My TypeScript WebStorm settings:

[image: My WebStorm TypeScript settings]

Even when I specify `"files"` and `"include"` options in `tsconfig.json` to point to my `*.ts` files no errors appear, though in my previous (non-angular) app everything works fine. If I run `tsc` in my project root I get a bunch of expected error messages, but still no editor hints provided.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve the problem by opting out `"Angular language service"` as I was constantly getting an error message in the TypeScript console:
`Error:Initialization error (angular 2 language service). Cannot read property 'CommandTypes' of undefined`

[This is a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34463)

Comment: It says "Fixed" for 2018.3 version.